# How to use Jquery to colour the background of an element, based on keywords within the html 

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use Jquery to firstly identify specific words within a span tag, and then colour the background of a div it is nested in.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="highlight item1 ll3">
<div class="Image">
<h2 class="Name">
<div class="type">
<span>Workshop</span>
</div>
   <div class="Dates">
   <p class="Desc">Toddlers are especially welcome to BALTIC on Tuesdays. Join 
    in the fun, as a BALTIC artist leads a practical session using a variety of       
    materials,...
</p>
```

So I think I need to use Jquery to identify if  equals "Workshop" then color the div with class `highlight` (for e.g. set background to #000).  I need to repeat this so that each div.highlight that has a different  value is given a different color.

Thanks so much in advance.

Jason

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span:contains('Workshop')").parent().css({ "background-color" : "#f8f8f8" });
});
```

Comment: Hi James thanks very much for your time and effort I'm new to jquery so I'm made some assumptions that I need to add the 'document ready' line into the code:

<script type="text/javascript"> if 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span:contains('Workshop')").parent().css({ "background-color" : "#f8f8f8" });
});
</script>

unfortunately I can't get it working.  Jason

Comment: You don't need an `if` statement to check the document ready state. Just copy the code from my example above.

Comment: Hi James thanks again, I had to amend the code slightly as you can see but I've got it working. Only its coloured the div.type background and not div.Highlight any ideas?

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("span:contains(Workshop)").parent().css( "background-        color","red" );
    });
</script>

Comment: Glad you got it working. Make sure to mark the answer if you're satisfied. Happy programming ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this example if you are looking to add css based on keywords

http://tinkerbin.com/q6GwDrvJ

Comment: -1: How does this answer the question? It has nothing to do with what's being asked...

Comment: am sorry am new to this did not knew had to reply with the given problem. I just gave an example

Comment: Your answer ignores most of the question. OP is looking for keywords in a `<span>` and is looking to apply the background color to the parent element. Your answer accomplishes neither of these.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("span:contains(Workshop)").parent().css( "background-color","red" ); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of my answer. Check the other answers first before you post an almost identical answer.